# Email client does not working for Yahoo Mail

Tags: pantheon-mail

I am using the latest version of Elementary OS. I am trying to connect to my Yahoo Mail box, using Elementary's default mail client.

From the welcome window I selected "Yahoo Mail" and added my correct credentials. The error is:

```
Unable to validate:
    - Connection error.
```

I don't use `Two-step verification` in my account. I also tried to use the Yahoo Mail `smtp` and `imap` details to connect to a "custom server" with no success.

I also tried this: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-third-party-passwords-sln15241.html (I don't know what should I write at "Enter custom name", when generating password for an "Other app" - I tried with "Elementary") and used the generated password. Same error happens.

Some advices?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and it appears also into Ubuntu 18.04 Geary. Yesterday I did upgrade of Ubuntu into 20.04 and Yahoo started to work again with Geary withous any modifications. It looks like Yahoo! ignores the older versions of the mail app, which is the present one of Geary(so called Pantheon Mail) into elementary OS Hera....